# Problem: wp_query outputs all images on site

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop, images

I'm having issues with a query. I want to get the images attached to an individual post of the type *rental*.

My query is broken as it outputs all the images on the entire site:

```
$image_query = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'post_type' => 'attachment', 
        'post_status' => 'inherit', 
        'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'post_parent' => $rental->post->ID,
        'order' => 'DESC' 
    ) 
);

if( $image_query->have_posts() ){
 while( $image_query->have_posts() ) {
     $image_query->the_post();
     $imgurl = wp_get_attachment_url( get_the_ID() );
     echo '<div class="item">';
     echo '<img src="'.$imgurl.'">';
     echo '</div>';
 }

 wp_reset_postdata();

}
```

Any ideas on how I can adjust this to only get the images attached to the current post?

Comment: Clue: what is $rental?

Comment: $rental is my custom post type. I get the same result if I just use `'post_parent' => $post->ID` there too.

Comment: Okay, does $rental->post->ID give us the correct data?

Comment: No, that gives me the same set of data as `$post->ID`. Its a weird one thats for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the `post_parent` parameter, if this is set to 0 or a falsey value like null your query will return all top level posts.

So you just have to make sure $rental->post->ID has a value, or use a different approach like the `get_the_ID()` function.

Can't really tell you more than that as you have not included the part where you set `$rental`

```
$image_query = new WP_Query( 
    array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent' => get_the_ID(), // your issue here lays
    )
);
```

And check out the docs for more details:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that helped. I noticed that the function worked perfectly fine on a standard post. I basically ended up moving the function into functions.php:

```
function get_rental_carousel_images($rental_id) {

// loosely based on http://martyspellerberg.com/2011/11/outputting-the-wordpress-attachments-gallery/

global $rental;

$images = get_children( array(
    'post_parent' => $rental_id,
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order ID'
) );

if ($images) :

    foreach ($images as $attachment_id => $image) :

        $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );

        ?>

        <img src="<?php echo $img_url; ?>" />

    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif;
```

and then outputting images in my template like this:

`<?php get_rental_carousel_images( get_the_ID() ); ?>`